# How to restart rsyslog on alpine?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog, alpine, syslogd

In my alpine 3.1..5 linux docker container, I installed rsyslog as:

```
# apk add --no-cache rsyslog
```

I am running rsyslogd as:

```
# rm -f /var/run/rsyslogd.pid
# rsyslogd
```

How do I restart rsyslogd without restarting my container? I tried:

```
# sudo service rsyslog restart
sudo: service: command not found
```

Also, the directory /etc/init.d/ is empty.

These are the processes in my container.

```
# ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
1 root      0:00 haproxy -W -db -f /usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
9 root      0:00 rsyslogd
16 root      0:00 /bin/sh
54 root      0:00 rsyslogd
59 root      0:00 rsyslogd
```

Thank you.

Comment: If that's the only process in your container (which it should be), then you can't.

Comment: @jordanm, haproxy is also running in the container.

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me:

```
kill -HUP $(pidof rsyslogd)
```